# Will a Wings of Liberty campaign be any different with the Heart of the Swarm extension?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I have the Heart of the Swarm extension pack installed with my StarCraft II, will the Wings of Liberty campaign be affected by it? (I.e. new terran units, new upgrades, etc?)

I don't mean for the plot to change (because that would obviously not change), but is there anything different between playing it with the extension pack and without?

Comment: A good question! I imagine some of the new UI features might change the experience slightly, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Would be fun to have custom game where players use the campaign units in an otherwise normal match even though some of those units are OP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have the new UI features (workers per mineral patch, change on the look of attack commands, etc.) since they got implemented in WoL too. However, I have not noticed any changes in the units as all the Terran units are Campaign only (marauder don't have stim, medics, banshees with splash, etc.)

Comment: And the enemy won't have jumping banelings or swarm HoTS!

Comment: You get the new UI features without buying HotS, though.

Answer (score 2):

A short answer to your question:
**Your WOL will not be affected by HOTS in anyway!**

(The only changes if you will, is the patch released prior to the release of HOTS - this is not due to HOTS as it was a patch for WOL)

There is no difference at all, whether you play with, or without HOTS expansion.

Comment: As Atlas point out the only changes will be to the interface and a few minor tweaks how minerals are gathered that are shared between the current WoL patch and HoTs patch.  This includes all interfaces outside of the actual match gameplay also.